# Set class variables to associative array keys with same name?

Tags: php, class, associative-array, laravel-5.7

I'm making a website using Laravel. I have a `Model` for posts. I have a static method `getPost` that is supposed to make a new instance of my `Post` model using an associative array of columns in the table `posts`.

I would like to have corresponding variables in the `Post` model class that have the same name as the columns in the table.

i.e.

```
Posts:
 _________________________________________________
|  id  |  title  | ...etc |                       |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|  1   |  This   |        |                       |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|  2   |  That   |        |                       |
```

Then in my class:

```
<?php

class Post extends Model
{
    public $id, $title;

    public function __construct(array $attributes = [], $data = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        if(!is_object($data)) return;

        /*Set $this->title = $data->title, $this->id = $data->id
          Except a quicker way to set variables of the same name to
          the corresponding key in the array without having to do the above
          for every single variable, which will become a problem as the
          the table grows and holds more data which is what I anticipate.*/
    }

    static public function getPost($id)
    {
        $temp = new Post();
        $post = DB::table($temp->getTable())->where('id', $id)->first();

        return new Post([], $post);
    }
}
```

So as I stated, I want to have the variables in my class with the same name as the keys in the associative array to automatically be set to their values. I don't know of any way to do this currently. If need be I can set them manually in the constructor but I'm just curious if there's an easier, less painful way to do this? Like some sort of function or what not.

Thanks for any help or advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $this->$key = $value;
}
```

Comment: To be honest, I had no idea you could do that. Thank you very much sir. Works great! :)

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen no problem :) For future reference, variable property names fall under the category of 'variable variables' http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php - learning these has saved me a lot of time!